# Length of String8(ListOfCARD8) in X11 protocol

Tags: x11, protocols

I'm working on a proxy server for X11, that will also do some slight data manipulation(color depth, watermarking and some more) on certain data. I've got the connection up and running, and I'm manipulating the server ip in the connection on 177/UDP so the client connects correctly through the proxy instead of calling the server instead. In other words, I've got a fully functional proxy that proxies the data through port 6000 from the client to the server.

What I'm attempting to do now is to parse the data stream and locate the beginning and type of every message to weed out the data I'll just pass on from the data I need to manipulate. However, I hit a snag really early in this.

The data that I get from the client is a single byte with the byteorder('B' in my case, but I'm making it support both), followed by 2 bytes for the major version(3) and 2 bytes for the minor version(11). Both of these are designated CARD16 in the protocol specification(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1013).
Following this is an AuthorizationName, meaning the type of authorization to use, of type STRING8. STRING8 is designated in docs as LISTOFCARD8, meaning a list of 8-bit unsigned integers.

Here's where the problem is: I haven't the slightest how long the LISTOFCARD8 is.
Snip from specification : "the size of the length field may vary (it is not
necessarily the same size as a FOO), in some cases may be implicit,
and is not fully specified in this document.".

The actual data I've got, from byte 5 and onward in the datastream, is 0 0 12 0 10 0 0 and then the actual data stream(ASCII string "MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1"). I can't make out a valid string length from th bytes preceding it, and the string itself does not appear to be null terminated.

So, to my question, if it hasn't already come across: How can I determine the length of a ListOfFOO, or more specifically a ListOfCARD8, as set down in RFC 1013?

Thank you!
// Eric Johansson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 1013 is a never used, long obsolete, pre-release version of the X11 protocol spec that should be burned before reading and never ever used.

The correct current X11 protocol spec can be found at http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html or http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen this. This specification seems quite a bit more thorough, however I still can't find any specification for the length of the String8. String8 is just mapped to a LISTofCARD8, and LISTofFOO just says that the length is encoded "elsewhere".

Comment: Never mind, I found a new, better explanation of the connection message that explained the length. Thank you!

Comment: @EricJohansson If you're still around, please share!